# Transformar objeto en un array

Tags: html, array, arraylist, objeto, jsonarray

Este es mi objeto:

```
{
   primerNombre: "Amira"
   segundoNombre: "Thor"
   tercerNombre: "Santa"
}
```

El cual quiero transformarlo a un arreglo donde pueda quedar asi:

```
[
    {
       name : "Amira"
    },
    {
       name : "Thor"
    },
    {
       name: "Santa"
    }
]
```

y esta otra forma en la que el arreglo pueda quedar asi

```
[
    {
       type : "primerNombre"
    },
    {
       type : "segundoNombre"
    },
    {
       type: "tercerNombre"
    }
]
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma sencilla podría ser iterarlo a través de sus llaves:

```js
var obj = {
   primerNombre: "Amira",
   segundoNombre: "Thor",
   tercerNombre: "Santa"
}
console.log('Primera Opcion de la pregunta');
//Primera manera
var array = Object.keys(obj)
    .map(function(key) {
        return { name: obj[key] };
    });
console.log(array);

console.log('Segunda Opcion de la pregunta');
//Segunda manera
var result = Object.entries(obj);
var array2 = Object.keys(result).map(function(key){
    return { type: result[key][0] };
  });
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el objeto Object.keys() para obtener la lista de los atributos del objeto, con eso la recorres y construlles el objeto que necesites para incluirlo en una nueva lista de arrays.

```
var array_1 = [];
var array_2 = [];
Object.keys(op).forEach(x=> {array_1.push({type: x}); array_2.push({name: op[x]})})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.